# Obter apenas palavras de A-z e numeros 0-9

Tags: php, string

Como eu posso remover tudo que não seja letra e numero de uma *string*, ou seja remover (`!@#$%^&*():"><?}` etc.) e manter apenas as letras de a-z e números de 0-9

Comment: Pode utiliar varios str_replace em cascata substituindo por "" (string vazia). ou usar expressões regulares (nunca testei)

Comment: Alguma das respostas podem ser aceitas aqui?

Answer (score 1):

É só usar o [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$chars = array('!', '@', '#');
echo str_replace($chars, '', 'oh! texto com # e @ para apagar!');
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cBQKcU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jnesapzo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/Replace.php).

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando a seguinte expressão regular:

`[^\w]`

E fazer a substituição utilizando `preg_replace`:

```
$texto = 'Ex#em$!plo uti@!lizando r3gex';
echo preg_replace('/[^\w]/', '', $texto);
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/KDX9cu)